# page redirect to another html page in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Requirement is to redirect from 'index.html' to 'userdetails.html' page on click of button (`type = button`)

I have 3 forms in index.html (each form to serve different purpose)
All have `method=Post`.

In the second form, I have a button with `type=button` and `id=userdetails`, and `onclick="sendDetails()"`

Now function on same page:

```
function sendDetails(){
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/newColl",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#form2').attr('action', '/userdetails');
        }
```

Now I have index.js page which has following function:

```
var createGroup = function(//<manipulation on mongodb>)

router.get('newColl', function(req, res, next){
    // mongo connection and calling createGroup function
    // this is working fine.
   client.close()
});

router.post('/userdetails', function(req, res, next) {
    res.redirect('userdetails.html');
}
```

I tried with `res.redirect`, `res.sendFile`, `res.render`, `window.location.href(in html)`, but all in vain.

Please can anybody guide.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manage a redirect request after a jQuery Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call)

Comment: You mentioned 3 forms, but only described one (I assume "the second form" is `#form2`).  Do the other two forms matter?  The way it's coded, it looks like you want the user to click the button in `#form2` twice.  Was that your intent?

Comment: Thanks...yes second form is #form2, the other forms have different purpose. In this second form, on click of button, I want to process some text search and result of that search to be stored in new field in new collection and once this is done..take it to next page where data will show from newly created collection.